# Hub site global navigation: is it normal that every child site must be added manually?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, navigation, global-navigation, hub-site

Associated hubs and Associated Child hubs do not automatically add the subordinates?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a known limitation of hub associations in SharePoint.

As per the Microsoft official documentation [Add links to hub associations to the hub site navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/hub-to-hub-association#add-links-to-hub-associations-to-the-hub-site-navigation),

> Navigational links to associated hubs are not automatically updated when there are changes to hub associations in the SharePoint admin center.

I will suggest first add/associate all SharePoint sites to a hub and then try adding  Associated hubs link to the navigation.